# Access an existing main winform instance from any child form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working a WinForm Application. I have a couple of forms on it. I want to be able to access my main form from any child form. I was able to do that through a custom button function and capture the Form_Closing event. I have one problem though which I'll explain below.

The code on the main form is as follow:

```
ChildForm form = new ChildForm(); // Create new Child Form instance
form.Show(); // Show Child form
this.Hide(); // Hide Main form
```

Using "this.Hide();" means that the main form still exists in memory and is still working, it's just hidden which is what I want.

The code on the child form

```
MainForm form = new MainForm(); // Create new Main Form instance
form.Show(); // Show Main Form
this.Close(); // Close Child Form
```

This is all well except on my second code block (Child Form directly above), the first line of code, creates a new instance of the main form. That is my problem, I don't want to create a new instance of that form, I want to show the already existing hidden instance (The main form I hid in the first block of code above).

I tried the following code on the Child form:

```
this.Parent.Show();
```

But I got this runtime error message:
"System.NullReferenceException was unhandled: Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I understand what the error means, I just don't the code to create an object reference to that main form or how to reference it in any sort.

Any tips please?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: pass the form reference via constructor `form2(IWin32Window parent)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do it. Because these are single thread forms, the function will wait till you close the form before proceeding further.

```
ChildForm form = new ChildForm(); // Create new Child Form instance
this.Hide(); // Hide Main form
form.ShowDialog(); // Show Child form, wait for closing
this.Show();
```

You can also attach ChildForm closing event to function in MainForm.

```
public MainForm()
{
    ChildForm form = new ChildForm();
    form.FormClosed += OnClosed;  
}
public void OnClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This has worked. It surprises me how simple things can be sometimes if you just had the knowledge for it. That answered my question. Thanks. (How do I set my question answered though? :) )

Comment: @YousefImran There's an outline of a checkmark just to the left of the post.  Click it to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a constructor for your other forms that takes in a window as a parameter

```
private Form MyParent { get; set; }
public Form1(Form parent)
{
   MyParent = parent;
}

MyParent.Show();
```

where `MyParent` is a property of the form

you can call this via `new ChildForm(this)`

---

**Edit**

I just looked, not sure why I can't use a constructor  for an `IWin32Window` but `Show` has an overload that takes one in which will set the `Owner` to a parent form

```
new ChildForm().Show(this);
ChildForm.Owner //returns MainForm (parent)
```

Comment: I get 2 syntax errors for that line 'this.ParentForm = parent' , first error says that the property 'ParentForm' is read only. Second error is that it cannot implicitly convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window' to 'Sytem.Windows.Forms.Form' , an explicit conversion exists.

Comment: oh sorry i didn't realise there was already a parent form parameter (I meant it as a property you create), the second one I find surprising though... you can use `Form` in place of IWin32Window.. I'll try to figure out why

Comment: @Sayse maybe you can't use IWin32Window because it isn't managed? Haven't used it, but looks like WinApi class rather than .Net

Comment: @MichaelCwienczek - I did a test and it was because of inheritance i believe, all forms are iwin32windows, but not all win32windows are forms.. `IWin32Window f = new Form()` works, but `Form f = new IWin32Window()` doesn't